# how to set default autoincrement value in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I have users table which autoincremented id automatically increased to high amount like `996165754` and I want to set autoincrement default value should start from `1260`

[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: is this HeidiSQL?

Comment: yes this is heidiSQL

Comment: there is an option at top tab of the table configuration (Table: ...). Click it and you will see the AI configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's auto-increment mechanism will not generate values lower than the max `id` value.

You can insert lower values if you specify them yourself, but you can't get auto-increment to make one. It will always generate a value at least one greater than the highest existing value.

You can try `ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT=1260` but you will find it automatically raises to max(id)+1 even if you specify a lower value.

Your only solution is to eliminate the high values, either by deleting the rows or changing their id values, and then `ALTER TABLE` to reset the next auto-increment value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any reason to alter this value. Autoincremented primary key column must be used for referential and integrity checking purposes exclusively. In general nobody must affect it, and even there is no reason to see it. It's not meant for you.

If you need a column with small numbers - then create one more column for this purposes and fill it with the values which you need. Or enumerate rows in a query.

You cannot set autoincrement autoassigned values to a value less than maximal value already present in a table.